# Why Taxify install error on Oneplus 3T in PlayStore website command?

Tags: google-play-store, installation, 7.1-nougat, oneplus-3

I have managed to install many other applications in my new phone but not Taxify, [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ee.mtakso.client&utm_source=Taxify%20invite_web&utm_medium=website&utm_term=main%20CTA&utm_content=android%20client%20app&utm_campaign=download%20app) download page, in the PlayStore HTML pages. I get the following error. 
The error message is weird because the Google account is associated with the phone, and I also have managed to install other applications such as Skype, WhatsApp, ... on the phone. 
I restarted my phone, and the problem persists. 
I have a stable internet connection.

[image]

Differential solution: install the application directly in the Android phone PlayStore. This indicates that there is some problem with the PlayStore HTML frontend with Oneplus 3T. 
After doing the installation this way, you will get *Installed* sign in the PlayStore website frontend too.

### Oneplus support chat proposal

> We can try to perform a clear cache via recovery mode.

- Power off your device.
- Press the power key + volume down for a few seconds.
- Select English.
- Look for Wipe data and cache
- Please select Wipe Cache only.

So this proposal indicates that there might be a cache problem in the phone.

Phone: Oneplus 3T
OS: Android 7.1.1
Phone: used one but did 2x factory reset before use

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem is most likely resulting from the system differences between Android and Oneplus.